# how to get digitemp output with node.js?

Tags: node.js, exec

I am trying to read DS18B20 temparature sensors executing `digitem` from node.js but I am no temperature values in the output. Here is the code:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

child = exec('/usr/bin/digitemp_DS9097 -s /dev/ttyUSB0 -a',
  function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + stdout);
    console.log('stderr: ' + stderr);
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log('exec error: ' + error);
    }
});
```

The output:

```
stdout: DigiTemp v3.5.0 Copyright 1996-2007 by Brian C. Lane 
GNU Public License v2.0 - http://www.digitemp.com
```

If I execute the command `/usr/bin/digitemp_DS9097 -s /dev/ttyUSB0 -a` in the linux shell I get the results.
I can get sensors list with `-w` option in node.js so the problem is not with reading the sensors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with digitem executed from node.js. Digitemp uses .digitemprc config file from home folder but node.js does not respect it and ignores or do not look in users home folder. I have to define confing file manualy to use or generate/copy config file in the same folder as node.js files are.